# How to stop execution of function twice in php laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I have a piece of PHP code I want to be executed once per time.
I see however that it can be run twice and this is causing the double updates to the database which is not desirable.

NOTE:
I call the function through an external cron event every 1 minute.
I have more than 5000 records but I want to update them in 100s.
What is the best way to implement this?

I call https://example.com/cron and it runs this function

```
DB::transaction(function() {
    $events = Event::where('status', 'ACTIVE')->take(100)->get();
    foreach ($events as $key => $event) {
        if(Log::where('event_id', $event->id)->exists()){
            $details = Detail::where('event_id', $event->id)->first();
            if($details->status == 1){
                // update details
                DB::transaction(function () use($event, $details) {
                    $value = $event->value+$details->value;
                    $event->update('status', 'INACTIVE');
                    $event->user->increment('count', $value);
                }, 5);
            }
        }
    }
}, 5);
```

The issue is that on the next run, the user count is doubled whenever I call the endpoint manually. But I think that the value of status should be inactive and that the function should be locked before the next call is made?
I am confused and don't understand why two simultaneous calls will have access to the table.

Comment: If you want to prevent access to the table by two simultaneous queries the naïve thing to do is to lock the tables. In MySQL you'd use [`LOCK TABLES`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/lock-tables.html)

Comment: Thank you for responding. How can I do that in Laravel? Also, isn't using transactions enough?

Comment: No the transaction ensures the operations are atomic, it does not prevent other operations to happen concurrently. To do this in Laravel check out [pessimistic locking in the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queries#pessimistic-locking)